# jTextArea locked Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, textarea

I'm programming in Netbeans 8 and ran into a problem. It's a chat application and I want the UTF messages that im receiving to appear in jTextArea1. But when i'm writing:

```
jTextArea1.append(receivedmessage);
```

I'm getting an error: A NON STATIC VARIABLE JTEXTAREA1 CAN NOT BE REFFERENCED FROM A STATIC CONTEXT.

And when I'm trying to change jTextArea1 to static its locked, and i can't do anyting. Do i have to unlock it or is there antoher solution? The only file in the projext is the "jFrame".

Comment: You need to Google that error as it is a common one for newbies and the fix is usually the same.

Comment: Ok i thougt it was a tough problem that only I ran in to, sorry.